# ¿Cómo puedo en una consulta según un valor tenga que ocupar un where distinto?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una consulta que según si el valor de un campo es NULL o no, en el where debería tener una condición o no.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 1):

No comprendo bien tú pregunta pero espero esto te sirva.
La función "`case`" compara 2 o más valores y devuelve un resultado.
La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
 case VALORACOMPARAR
  when VALOR1 then RESULTADO1
  when VALOR2 then RESULTADO2
  ...
  else RESULTADO3
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las reglas de la lógica. Recuerda que usando `AND` ambas codiciones deben evaluarse como verdaderas, pero usando `OR` solo una de ellas debe serlo. Por lo tanto, puedes usar algo así

```
SELECT *
FROM MiTabla
WHERE (ColumnaX = @ParametroX OR @ParametroX IS NULL)
AND (ColumnaY = @ParametroY OR ColumnaY IS NULL);
```

En la primer condición, tenemos de que la condición se evalue sólo si el parámetro tiene algún valor. En la segunda, condición evaluamos que la columna sea igual al parámetro o nula.

La primera opción es algo que puede causar problemas de optimización, por lo que es bueno evitarlo, agregar la opción `RECOMPILE`, o generar la consulta mediante código dinámico con las condiciones necesarias. De cualquier forma, será mejor que usar un CASE puesto que esa posibilidad está destinada a no usar índices.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo muy de cerca lo que medio explicas creo que seria mejor utilizar una combinación de lo que anteriormente te respondieron de la siguiente manera:

```
CASE WHEN "TUVALOR" 
IS NULL THEN "CONDICIÓN1"
ELSE "CONDICIÓN2" END AS "VALORFINAL"
```

De esta manera haces el case especifico si el valor es null sera la primera condición y si es diferente de **NULL** la condición 2.

Saludos.